# Framework7 Swiper with multiple columns per view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I would like to have a "grid" of images and the slider to give me the ability to have 3 columns per view of the slider. So every time you swipe up or down a new set of 3 images is displayed.

How is this possible with Framework7's slider? I have tried

```
 mySlider2 = myApp.slider('.slider-2', {
    pagination: '',
    spaceBetween: 4,
    slidesPerColumn" 3,
    direction: 'vertical'
});
```

I imagine it should be columns per row or something like that but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the structure framework7 provide and build the grid inside each slide by yourself.

```
<!-- Slider container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Slides wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            // Build your grid here
        </div>
        ... other slides ...
    </div>
    <!-- Pagination, if required -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the [Swiper API Docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) there is an option for defining how much slides should be visible at once. It is called `slidesPerView` not `slidesPerColumn` what you figured out.